# Sorting of the factor/character column that consists of numbers

Tags: r

i am not able to sort data.frame on base of column ID.

Here is sample data:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("542_1_3", "542_1_3", "542_1_3", "542_1_11", 
                              "542_1_11", "542_1_11", "542_1_14", "542_1_14", "542_1_14", "542_1_14", 
                              "542_1_14", "542_1_3", "542_1_3", "542_1_3", "542_1_11", "542_1_11", 
                              "542_1_11", "542_1_14", "542_1_14", "542_1_14", "542_1_14", "542_2_1"
), X = c(17.55, 23.75, 387.9, 148.3, 300.6, 413.1, 
                       41.85, 148.4, 237.7, 301.6, 414.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                       0, 0), Y = c(931, 924.2, 632, 789.8, 689.9, 637.8, 901, 
                                          809.5, 735.4, 675, 637, 953, 953, 953, 968.5, 968.5, 968.5, 959, 
                                          959, 959, 959, 959)), .Names = c("ID", "X", "Y"
                                          ), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
                                                           "14", "15", "16", "21", "31", "81", "91", "101", "111", "121", 
                                                           "131", "141", "151"), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using this data in my shiny app, and while plotting according to ID column, the legend gets mixed up and the values are not ordered. so for example instead of getting in legend ID order of:

```
"542_1_3", "542_1_11", "542_1_14","542_2_1"
```

I get:

```
"542_1_11", "542_1_14", "542_1_3","542_2_1"
```

**I cannot set the ID levels manually** because as this data belongs to reactive plot, the levels changes in dependence of the choosen ID values, plus number of levels is too high.

**[EDIT]**

Here is better reproducible example:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("544_1_11", "544_1_3", 
                                                      "544_1_7"), class = "factor"), `T8/5.5 Zeit [s]` = c(NA_real_, 
                                                                                                           NA_real_, NA_real_), Value = c(968, 949, 972)), .Names = c("ID", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "T8/5.5 Zeit [s]", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

whereas code:

```
data$ID <- with(data, factor(ID, levels = unique(ID)))
```

is not changing levels of ID column

```
levels(data$ID)
[1] "544_1_11" "544_1_3"  "544_1_7"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements

```
data$ID <- with(data, factor(ID, levels = unique(ID)))
levels(data$ID)
#[1] "542_1_3"  "542_1_11" "542_1_14" "542_2_1"
```

#### Update

In the new dataset, the `unique` IDs are not in the correct order.  So, we can use `mixedsort` from `gtools` on the 'ID' and use that as `levels` in the `factor` call.

```
library(gtools)
data$ID <- with(data, factor(ID, levels = mixedsort(as.character(ID))))
```

Comment: It actually did not do anything to my `data.frame`

Comment: @Malvina_a  It does change the order of levels,  Please check it

Comment: Yes you are right, it does, but still in my shiny app the order is wrong..I have no idea now

Comment: @Malvina_a  We can't test it without any reproducible example

Comment: I have just added a sample data, which does not react to the code `data$ID <- with(data, factor(ID, levels = unique(ID)))`

Comment: Hi @akrun, is there any other way to change the levels rather then downloading this package?(I am working on RStudio Server and installing new package will take time as i need to get in contact with people who are responsible for server)

Comment: @Malvina_a  In that case, try `data$ID <- with(data, factor(ID, as.character(unique(ID[do.call(order, lapply(strsplit(as.character(ID), "_"), function(x) as.numeric(x)))]))))`